# Create local SQL database from AS/400 Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-schema

I want to create local a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 using AS/400 schema...how can i do that..i don't know what is AS/400 schema in SQL...i tried to search on internet but not able to find any helpful link.
Please help me.

Comment: is there an ODBC/JDBC driver for AS400? if so then there may be more tools there.  Also, do you have budget for tools? or should this somehow be free? :)

Comment: Here's a link that might be useful:
http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/as400-to-sql-server-data-migration/

Comment: Is there any tool require for that..?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to extract the file structures from the AS/400 and manually create, I know of no automated method, the corresponding SQL tables.

Comment: How can i create a local database in SQL Server using AS/400 Schema..please give me a sample example.

Comment: You can not is the basic answer. You must create the schema and tables as normal in SQL Server - or are you asking how to migrate the data? If it is the data then @PaddyC's answer is most appropriate. But you must first create the tables in SQL Server before implementing the data pump.